# NodeJs Big scale routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-routing

I'm trying to build a router that has around 200,000 options

The design is that each client will send it's data and will be redirected to another link, with 200,000 different client possibilities.

I read that NodeJs is good at handling lot of requests at very high speeds.

But when I implemented my server with a Javascript object as a large dictionary (each property is a key) it could only handle around 1800 requests per second.

Is there a better way to implement such routing design?

Thank you!

Comment: What part specifically appeared to be slow when you profiled ?

Comment: How can I profile it? I only saw that the CPU is at 100%... which explains nothing

Comment: that dictionary sounds like the source of the problem, have you thinked about using more efficent storage methods?

Comment: I'd be willing to be that you're instantiating that dictionary on every request...

Comment: I agree. Definitely gotta do some profiling. It's usually pretty straightforward. Just grab the current timestamp at the beginning of the function, and then subtract from current on callback and you've got a benchmark.

Comment: Once you figure out where your bottleneck is, then you can really address the issue. (Hunch is on that dict.) Once you figure it out, I'd suggest memcached for a key/value lookup.

Comment: also did you consider making the routing dynamic if its possible?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. reading from dictionary takes less then 1 ms, so i get 0 at the tracing i'm adding. I'm not instantiating the dicionary on every request, the instatiating log is written once.
What other routing options are possible? what is dynamic routing?